# Crosswalk Cordova basic example builds but won't run

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

Has anyone else experienced this?

I've followed these instructions:
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started/windows_host_setup.html

and then these:
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/develop_an_application.html

everything appears to be fine - the build claims to succeed and does indeed produce a .APK but this won't run either in an emulator or on a device. THe .APK installs ok but stops immediately with the message "Unfortunately, app4 has stopped."

any help - or even a suggestion of what to try next most appreciated...

further details:
java version 1.8.0_25
ant version 1.9.4
python version 3.4.2
adb 1.0.32

crosswalk package - Cordova Android (ARM) 8.37.189.12

Comment: On the emulator side, probably you are using an X86 emulator while testing a ARM apk created by crosswalk.  Are you able to deploy the APK without using Crosswalk [with only Cordova ] ?

Comment: no - definitely running an ARM emulator

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'deploy the APK without using Crosswalk'?  It is the example app created by the crosswalk package

Comment: Ok I see, I though that you had a Cordova app then converting it Crosswalk. If nothing helps here, crosswalk has a really good mailing list and usually the crosswalk developers are answering directly.

Comment: thanks - i will try that - I have just tried the basic helloword cordova app (ie not using crosswalk) and that works fine which suggests the fault is with my crosswalk install

Comment: turns out I was creating the project on the command line with other programs running (eclipse etc) which corrupted the project folders...    Still can't get it to work in the emulator though :(

Answer (score 2):

For me the Crosswalk runtime would only successfully start if the `Use Host GPU` option in the AVD wizard was checked.

I did not find this right away, and was running into the same issue you describe. The "Use Host GPU" note is in their tutorial for android though --> https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started/android_target_setup.html